# Transfering a file using ftp from one server to another in different location

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I have a requirement of transferring a document file (.txt, .xls, .doc, .bmp, .jpg etc) from one server to another server. Both servers are at different locations. My main application is running on second server. And I have to deploy this functionality on the first server from where the files in any fixed folder (say D:\documents) will be transferred to second server periodically at any timer event.

I am using a code like as follows

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.UploadFile("ftp://1.23.153.248//d://ftp.bmp", 
    @"C:\Documents and Settings\varun\Desktop\ftp.bmp");
```

I am getting the error as

```
unable to connect to remote server
```

or

```
sometime underlying connection was closed
```

Could you tell me what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Is your ftp public? if no you should define credentials like this

```
wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("username","password");
```

before sending file, and try to remove d: from ftp path. ftp clients don't have to know where on server files should be saved... shortly try this

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("username","password");
wc.UploadFile("ftp://1.23.153.248/ftp.bmp", @"C:\Documents and Settings\varun\Desktop\ftp.bmp");
```

There are also classes created specially for ftp request in .net, here is sample from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715.aspx)

```
 // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.contoso.com/test.htm");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("anonymous","janeDoe@contoso.com");

            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader("testfile.txt");
            byte [] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine("Upload File Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription);

            response.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

The URI of your FTP location seems to be off: you shouldn't have to double all the forward slashes, and I don't think drive letters are supported.

If you do:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.UploadFile("ftp://1.23.153.248/ftp.bmp",
    @"C:\Documents and Settings\varun\Desktop\ftp.bmp");
```

The file will be sent to the directory set as the FTP location for the anonymous user. If you configure the FTP service on `1.23.153.248` so that location is `D:\`, everything should work as planned.